# Meaning of "nonexistent" in "Because his delivery was halting, the effect of his speech on the voters was nonexistent."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, adjectives

I know that **nonexistent** means not exist or not real. But in this context what does nonexistent mean. Is it meaning his speech is not real or effective.

> Because his delivery was halting, the effect of his speech on the voters was **nonexistent**.

Comment: His speech was not effective. Since **delivery** is mentioned, we know that the speech itself took place ("*to deliver a speech*"), but it's effect was negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His speech was not effective. Since **delivery** is mentioned, we know that the speech itself took place ("*to deliver a speech*" is a common collocation), but it's effect was negligible.

Comment: you are right. I bogged down in this sentence also. Could you please help to understand this sentence. Madison was not communicative person and thus made few public addresses; but those he made were memorable, filled with noble phrases. Thus made few public addresses, I did not get this point. I will be greatful if you could clarify this sentence also for me.

Comment: @androidcodehunter - "*and because of this he rarely spoke before the public*". By the way, you could just start a new question on this instead of asking in the comments section - *and thus get more chances for an answer*. (0:

Comment: thanks Here I asked the question http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68557/what-does-few-public-addresses-mean-in-this-context