# What does "few public addresses" mean in "Madison was not a communicative person and thus made few public addresses"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Madison was not a communicative person and thus made few public
>   addresses; but those he made were memorable, filled with noble
>   phrases.
>   <sub>-- [How to Prepare for the New SAT](https://books.google.com/books?id=8fP3YFwl1Q4C&pg=PA85) by Sharon Weiner Green, Ira K. Wolf</sub>

In this above context what does **few public addresses** mean and also the sentence said that

> but those he made were memorable, filled with noble phrases.

Does it mean he made memorable friendship or communication with people whom he met. Could anyone help me to understand the whole meanning of this sentence.

Comment: 4b: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/address, speeches.

Comment: A speech. A known historical example is the [Gettysburg address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_Address) by Lincoln.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Madison was not a communicative person and thus made few public addresses; but those he made were memorable, filled with noble phrases.

Madison was not an outgoing person. He lacked the confidence or desire to socialize with large numbers of people.

Because of this, he rarely made speeches before large gatherings of people.

But he still made some speeches, maybe because he needed to.

All the speeches that he made were memorable. They were filled with noble phrases.

---

The word **few** means **small number**. He made a small number of public addresses.

Note, however, [that "**few**" is different in meaning from "**a few**"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/a-few-vs-few).